# Access 2007 - Using results of an equation inside another equation on a report

Tags: ms-access

I inserted three text boxes to test how this could work:
Text81: =1
Text82: =2
Text83: I want this one to be the sum of Text81 and Text82

Thanks in advance for your help on what I think is a pretty simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple options that spring to mind.

First you could always modify the data source for the report to include the calculated field.

Second, which is what your question drives at, you can do something like this:

=[Text81] + [Text82]

Should work when typed into the Control Source of a TextBox provided Text81 and Text82 are the data field names from the Data Source of the Report.  If they are not you would put the corresponding data field names in the square brackets []

Hope this helps